# How to get a list of rds snapshots older than x days

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to get a list of rds snapshots older than x days. Using the describe-snsapshots cli.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-snapshots.html

```
expiry_date=$(date -d "-10 days" +'%Y-%m-%d')

 aws rds --region us-east-2 describe-db-snapshots --filters Name=db-instance-id,Values=acme --query 'DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime<`2023-01-10`].DBSnapshotIdentifier'expiry_date
```

However im having trouble substituting the raw date with the variable `expiry_date`

```
 aws rds --region us-east-2 describe-db-snapshots --filters Name=db-instance-id,Values=acme --query 'DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime<`$expiry_date`].DBSnapshotIdentifier'
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables don't get expanded inside single quotes (`'`).  Use double quotes (`"`) instead:

```
aws rds --region us-east-2 describe-db-snapshots --filters Name=db-instance-id,Values=acme --query "DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime<\`$expiry_date\`].DBSnapshotIdentifier"
```

Note that the backquotes are backslash-escaped because they are expanded (an archaic form of command substitution (`$(...)`) inside double quotes.